# Windows form AximageEdit control event initialization-Mouseup event C sharp

Tags: c#, winforms

In designer i have initialized the mouse up event like below
this.axImgEdit1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.axImgEdit1_MouseUpEvent);

and in code behind , event is written like below.
private void axImgEdit1_MouseUpEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

but in run time it is throwing error.
event mouse up is not valid on this activeX control

aximageedit also has its own eventargs, but if i write that it throw compile time error like no overload for matches delegate 'system.eventhandler'

how to handle this third party control events in windows form

Comment: What is `AximageEdit` control? Tagging question with library tag may bring developers attention to the question.

Comment: It is third party control

Comment: Can you ask *third party* for support? Otherwise to get information about mouse events over something you can use [hacky](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4991044/1997232) methods: mouse hooks, processing windows message, etc.