# Catch a mouse click event on a control

Tags: c#, .net, click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling a Click for all controls on a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form)

I have a user control, I add controls on this user control. All of children will cover user control' region. That mean, you don't have any space to click on user control.

My problem how to detect user mouse click on this user control's region.

Please give me the best solution without add mouse click event handler on each child to detect mouse click. Thanks.

Comment: posible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form

Comment: Note: Mouse click event on user control will don't be raised because you are clicking on a its child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per you can do following

1. handle control click event
2. in that event check the sender -- its of your control type

This will do your task

**For Example** -- here I am handling button click event (you can handle click event of your control)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is Button)//MyControl in you case 
    {
     //your code 
    }
}
```