# How to distinguish whether Enter event was raised by keyboard or mouse click?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, focus

Is there a way to distinguish whether the `Enter` event on a control was raised by keyboard (Tab, Shift+Tab) or by direct mouse click?

I need to perform an action only when the user is moving to the control using Tab, but not when the user directly clicks on the control. I have tried to intercept the mouse click directly, but it seems the `Enter` event is raised before `Click`.

Comment: How do you do ENTER with a mouse?

Comment: You click on the control

Comment: I see what you mean. Handle the key down event and check if tab is pressed and the target control has focus and then do whatever you need.

Comment: You mean using `ProcessCmdKey`? Maybe that could work...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tracking the `Tab` key, you can use the [WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645612(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect activation of the control with the mouse.  You could either sub-class each control type you use and override the `WndProc` method or use a [NativeWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) listener class like the one presented below.  Depending on how many types of controls you use, it may be less work and clutter to just sub-class those controls to provide a property that indicates that the control was selected using the mouse.  It is your decision to make, but the pattern will be the same.

This code is a slight modification of the example shown in the MS documentation.

```
public class MouseActivateListener : NativeWindow
{
    private Control parent;

    public MouseActivateListener(Control parent)
    {
        parent.HandleCreated += this.OnHandleCreated;
        parent.HandleDestroyed += this.OnHandleDestroyed;
        parent.Leave += Parent_Leave;
        this.parent = parent;
        if (parent.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            AssignHandle(parent.Handle);
        }
    }

    private void Parent_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseActivated = false;
    }

    private void OnHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssignHandle(((Form)sender).Handle);
    }

    private void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseHandle();
    }

    public bool MouseActivated { get; set; }


    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const Int32 WM_MouseActivate = 0x21;

        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_MouseActivate && m.Result.ToInt32() < 3)
        {
            MouseActivated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MouseActivateListener textBox1Listener;
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        textBox1Listener = new MouseActivateListener(textBox1);
    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1Listener.MouseActivated)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse Enter");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tab Enter");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Form.KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) event and store the last key press in a variable. Then in your control's `Enter` event, check the value of the key that was pressed last. If this is a tab, do whatever you need to:

```
private Keys lastKeyCode;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.lastKeyCode = e.KeyCode;
}
```

Then in the `Enter` event, check it:

```
if (lastKeyCode == Keys.Tab)
{
    // Whatever...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `PreviewKeyDown` event doesn't seem to be raised before the `Enter` event. Also `ProcessCmdKey` doesn't really work because you only know when the Tab key was pressed, but not when it was released.

Comment: @glopes Why do you have to perform this action in `Enter` event. Any specific reason?

Comment: UI design requirement, I need to trigger different actions depending if the control is entered using a key press or a mouse click, not much I can do about that.

Comment: @glopes See my edited answer please. A different approach.

Comment: This will not work because the user may press the Tab key, and then click the control before pressing any other key.

Comment: @glopes Ok but now the user has done both so which direction will you take? Anyhow, even that case can be handled if you also capture if the mouse was clicked as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form)

Comment: This seems like excessive bookkeeping, tracking the current state of the Tab key is enough. See my answer below, in the end I had to use a message filter instead of the form events because Tab is so hard to capture correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_KEYDOWN` directly with a message filter to retrieve the state of the Tab key worked. This seems excessive for such a seemingly straightforward task, but apparently the Tab key is suppressed from most windows forms events.

Would be happy to take a cleaner answer, but for now, this is it:

```
class TabMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool TabState { get; set; }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                if ((Keys)m.WParam == Keys.Tab) TabState = true;
                break;
            case WM_KEYUP:
                if ((Keys)m.WParam == Keys.Tab) TabState = false;
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class MainForm : Form
{
    TabMessageFilter tabFilter;

    public MainForm()
    {
         tabFilter = new TabMessageFilter();
         Application.AddMessageFilter(tabFilter);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
         Application.RemoveMessageFilter(tabFilter);
         base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }

    void control_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (tabFilter.TabState) // do something
         else // do domething else
    }
}
```

Comment: But even this approach is limited to what you commented towards my answer: "This will not work because the user may press the Tab key, and then click the control before pressing any other key." Am I missing something?

Comment: @CodingYoshi the problem is that I have other controls in my form. The user can press tab in another control and then move the mouse and click to select this control. The `Enter` event is raised between `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` so in this case I can be absolutely sure that the event was caused by the Tab key.

Comment: I agree it is convoluted, I was surprised myself that I could only find this way to do it.

Comment: I have not verified, but this technique may have issues with a TextBox that accepts Tabs.  Also, I would recommend overriding the form's OnActivated and OnDeactivate methods and attach/detach the filter in those methods.  Do you need this function for all controls on Forn or is a limited number.  If it is limited, you could attach a NativeWindow listener and listen for WM_MouseActivate.  This message is sent directly to the window and is not picked-up by the message pre-filter.

Comment: @TnTinMn can you elaborate on possible issues? I am using it with a TextBox that accepts tabs and it seems to work. My understanding is that the pre-filter runs before any controls in the form, and since I am not doing anything to the message (just logging the tab state), I am not interfering with the normal functioning of other controls.

Comment: @TnTinMn also, I am curious about the WM_MouseActivate approach. It might be worth it to post a solution, as there don't seem to be many examples lying around.

Comment: There is no issue with interference.  What I was concerned about was possible false positives; however after looking at the code again, I see that that is unlikely.  The basic listener example is in the the documentation for [NativeWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1);  but they always make it confusing, so I will post one shortly.