# Click Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello everyone There is a form that is inherited from other forms
I signed this form for the Click event, but it doesn't work for child controls, only for the form itself. In my opinion, it is necessary to register some property. Tell me, please

Comment: You may need to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form). Remember to exclude buttons if appropriate.

Comment: You can register the Click event wherever you want it to work. Note that usually you will not want it to work ony many controls like botton of all sorts etc. So, for selected controls you can simply paste the event name into theit events pane.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms, contained controls don't inherit the registered events of container control, you'll need to register the event for the controls you want.

You can loop in all the controls to register your intended event:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    control.Click += myForm_Click;
}
```

Comment: This will only include 1st level controls, like a GroupBox but nothing inside..

Comment: @TaW - Yup!, noticed that after Eugene Astafiev's answer. Also the link from Andrew on the question has a sample that deals with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to control events separately, you can do that recursively for every child control using the following code sample:

```
void SubscribeToControlsEventsRecursive(ControlCollection collection)
 { 
    foreach (Control c in collection)  
     {  
       c.MouseClick += (sender, e) => {/* handle the click here  */});  
       SubscribeToControlsEventsRecursive(c.Controls);
     }
 }
```

Comment: This will include everything, including each Button. Yes, that's what he may want but chances are he didn't think matters through ;-)

Comment: That code looks suspiciously similar to the question I linked in my comment above, LOL.

Comment: Are there any other recursive way of subscribing to the events?